# Toolbars invisible after restarting gdm

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, gdm

If I'm inside gnome in Ubuntu 10.04 and I open up a terminal and type "sudo restart gdm" I get back to the login screen. When I log in however all the toolbars are missing. If I maximize a window then it only maximizes up to where the toolbars should be. It's like the toolbars are invisible. How can I make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alt-F2` then `gnome-panel` then `Enter key`